# Excel - Disabel ability to manually change sheets (but don't hide them)

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this is a really stupid question but I've not been able to find a solution.

I've got a main page on my Excel workbook with a number of filter options and some buttons linked to vba code. When clicking the button it takes you another tab with a load of data filtered appropritately. There is a button there that removes the filters and takes you back.

This all works fine but what I want to do is stop people being able to manually change sheets but clicking on the tabs at the bottom of the screen. So far the only method I've found is hiding them, but this obviously doesn't work as you then can't see that data.

Comment: what is the point of being able to see the data on the sheets, but not being able to navigate them? In other words, if you don't want people to be able to navigate to the sheets but you want the data to be seen... it's not making sense. Do you want only certain people (like you as the developer) to see the sheets?

Comment: go to excel option > Advanced > Display options  and Uncheck 'Show sheet tabs'. This will hide the sheet tabs, so visually to a user it will show only main page. Make sure you have navigation link intact. However this will not disable changing sheet by Ctrl + PgDn.

Comment: Disabling the sheet tabs is exactly what I was after. Seems like such a simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the editing of the sheet tab names by turning them off on the excel options as mentioned in the comment above. The downside to this approach is the user won't be able to see what sheet they are on (which I find incredibly frustrating).

The better method in my mind is to set up an event listener for when the user changes the name of the tab. You can then send a pop up box that appears when the user attempts to change the tab name.